# Xcode not allowing me to see full target names

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode is acting weird like this:

[image]

For some reason I cannot seem to expand the Targets and Project tab so I cannot see which target is which.

Why is this question being down voted so much without a single comment
? I already tried moving the slider/divider to the right.

Comment: ... Have you tried dragging the divider to the right?

Comment: Yeah already tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug: every once in a while, the column of project and target names gets "wedged" in this position.

But the workaround is pretty easy: make the window wider / narrow until the expander widget starts working again. You might also have to switch out of target editing mode to the code editor and come back again. Basically you're just trying to slap the target editor on the side of the head.

Comment: And be sure to report the bug to Apple. The more reports of this bug they get, the better.